# Align a <p> with padding to edge of parent <div>

Tags: html, css

I have an image(which is a link) that has a caption directly below it, like this:

```
<div>
    <a href = "http://fake.com/link">
        <img src = "http://fake.com/picture">
    </a>
    <p>
        Caption here.
    </p>
</div>
```

I essentially want the image set on a gray background. I initially set the div's background to gray, which pretty much worked - but I noticed later that strips of gray are different widths around different images. Pretty much, I'm trying to make the border equal width around all images.

What I tried was rather than setting the background of the div to gray, setting a 5px border around the div and setting  the paragraph's background color to gray... The problem is that the edge of the paragraph's padding is lining up with the edge of the parent div - since the parent div has no background color, it leaves thin white strips on either side of the caption... Does anyone know how I could solve this?

Comment: All relevant code must be posted in your question, not through a live link.  Please fix this.

Comment: not sure what you are asking. but you will save a lot of time just making the two image the same size.

Comment: the two images in question have different sizes...just set their width and height to be the same thing

Comment: Make sure that `img` has alt text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question. I believe you're trying to get an equal border around the image? Add `box-sizing: border-box` to `.wp-caption` to regulate your padding

```
.wp-caption {
   background: #e1e1e1;
   border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
   max-width: 96%;
   padding: 5px 3px 0;
   text-align: center;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at the two images I noticed they both have a different width and height.  You need to give them a class that will control this for you if you want the padding around the images to be the same.

Comment: The thing is that the css I'm trying to edit right now is a class which is used for all images with a caption... so I don't want to limit them all to being the same size, and it would be nice to have the same width border around each image without having to manually change the size.

Comment: you can give an element multiple class references.  By CSS Order of Specification, "when two rules have the same weight, the last rule specified wins."